# Coverting string to dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like the below. How can I convert this string data to pandas dataframe?

```
data='"customer_id"|"first_name"|"city_name"\r\n123456"|"ABC"|"ARGENTINA"\r\n"2000142707"|"efgh"|"LOMELLO"\r\n
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `pd.read_csv`, and specify `sep="|"`

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|')
```

Of course, if you have the data in a file instead of a string, you can just read the file directly:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file", sep='|')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  customer_id first_name  city_name
0      123456        ABC  ARGENTINA
1  2000142707       efgh    LOMELLO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([i.split('|') for i in text.replace('"','').split('\r\n')])
```

You should do some modifications after to have the columns names and delete the last empty row.